# Shell injection with variable expansion within backticks in bash

Tags: bash, shell, code-injection

I'm looking to prevent shell injection.
I have some code as follows in my backend in bash:

```
`cmd $user_input1 $user_input2`
```

I haven't found a way to exploit this code yet. I was thinking if

`user_input1="| ls >/tmp/hi"`

then a file called `/tmp/hi` would be created. This is not the case since special characters like`|` seem to be ignored and are just passed as literal arguments to `cmd`. Is there anyway to interpret these special charters to do some shell exploits?

Comment: No, variables in backticks are not inherently exploitable in Bash.

Comment: The only special characters that are interpreted after variable expansion are `*`, and `?`.

Comment: Backticks and `$()` are not interpreted after variable expansion. Trivial example: `var='$(ls)'; echo $var`

Comment: Sorry, right, it's just wildcards.

Comment: You can't RCE it in the general case, but you can DoS it for a while with `/*/*/*/*/*/*/*`

Comment: @thatotherguy I see thank you. So `/*/*/*/*/*/*/*` might DoS if the file system was large. I guess that's not an issue since this is a small embedded system.

Comment: Any sort of expansion without double-quotes around it (both variables, like `$foo`, and command substitutions -- the backticked command) is subject to word splitting and wildcard expansion, with [hard-to-control consequenses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). So double-quote them. Also, many commands interpret any argument starting with a dash (or sometimes other characters) as an option, allowing unintended behavior. Some allow `--` as an end-of-options mark, but others don't.

Comment: BTW, while command substitution doesn't allow direct shell injection, [arithmetic mode does](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#read_num.3B_echo_.24.28.28num.2B-1.29.29) (at least in bash).

Comment: Does 'cmd' refers to window shell ? If this is the case, then the user can do  (almost) anything.